# Spring MVC REST Date input and timezones

Tags: spring-mvc, timezone, date-format

I'm working with Spring MVC and I have a custom date/datetime parser:

```
@Bean
public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
    DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

    DateTimeFormatterRegistrar dateTimeRegistrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
    dateTimeRegistrar.setDateFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    dateTimeRegistrar.setDateTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    dateTimeRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

    DateFormatterRegistrar dateRegistrar = new DateFormatterRegistrar();
    dateRegistrar.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    dateRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

    return conversionService;
```

}

I have some trouble with timezone and @PathVariable or @RequestBody inputs.

```
@GetMapping("/report/{date}")
public void testPath(@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date date){
   ...
}

@PostMapping("/report")
public void testBody(@RequestBody Date filter){
    ...
}
```

Calling this URL `http://localhost/report/2022-06-01` the first controller parses the date to **2022-06-01 00.00 CEST**

Calling this URL `http://localhost/report` with this body "2022-06-01" the second controller parses the date to **2022-06-01 +02.00 CEST** (adjusting the time adding +2h).

Is there any way to force the `FormattingConversionService` to consider the date to local timezone?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
With JsonFormat you can get the same date if you set timezone to your local.
Unfortunately, there is no way to set timezone dynamically.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", timezone = "Europe/Warsaw")
private Date date;
```

In my case, it only worked for POST RequestBody parameter. I couldn't change timezone of GET path parameter.